# How to relate two object in a json file when searching?

Tags: python, json, twitter, twitterapi-python

I'm using the Twitter API, and it returns me a JSON file.
There's a sample in their dev [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/place) if you scroll to the bottom, note the example only includes 1 tweet whereas I'm working with hundreds.

In the `data` object you have geo and inside of geo you have `place_id` which correlates to another field in the `includes` object, more specifically the `id` field nested under `places`.

My problem then arises when I have hundreds of tweets in a JSON file in `data` and their respective geolocation data in the other object `includes`. How can I extract the geolocation data and relate it to the current tweet I have selected?

Currently, I have a for loop to go through all of the tweets and append the information into a CSV file, then nested in that for loop I have this:

```
    for place in json_response['includes']['places']:
      if (geo == place['id']):
        full_name = place['full_name']
        country = place['country']
        country_code = place['country_code']
        new_geo = place['geo']
        place_name = place['name']
        place_type = place['place_type']
```

However, it only returns the geolocation data for 1 tweet per JSON response because I assumed that each tweet got its own `includes` object. Now I'm stuck and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the need for a double for loop as well as the if statement
you have in your code snippet a straightforward approach without an additional library would be to make a dict comprehension of all tweets with the `place_id` as the dict's key:

```py
tweets = {tweet['geo']['place_id']: tweet for tweet in json_response['data']}
```

this results in the following list:

```py
{'01a9a39529b27f36': {'text': 'We’re sharing a live demo of the new Twitter Developer Labs program, led by a member of our DevRel team, @jessicagarson #TapIntoTwitter [url_intentionally_removed],
  'id': '1136048014974423040',
  'geo': {'place_id': '01a9a39529b27f36'}}}
```

If the response returned more than one tweets, as you've mentioned your use case is then this would look like:
`['01a9a39529b27f36', 'some_other_id', ...]`

In the next step we can do a dict comprehension defining the id of each `place`, this way we can avoid any if-statements:

```py
places = { p['id']: p for p in json_response['includes']['places']}
```

this produces the following result:

```py
{'01a9a39529b27f36': {'geo': {'type': 'Feature',
   'bbox': [-74.026675, 40.683935, -73.910408, 40.877483],
   'properties': {}},
  'country_code': 'US',
  'name': 'Manhattan',
  'id': '01a9a39529b27f36',
  'place_type': 'city',
  'country': 'United States',
  'full_name': 'Manhattan, NY'}}
```

Finally, to combine them based on the common key:

```py
for pid, geodata in places.items(): tweets[pid].update(geodata)
```

which yields:

```py
{'01a9a39529b27f36': {'text': 'We’re sharing a live demo of the new Twitter Developer Labs program, led by a member of our DevRel team, @jessicagarson #TapIntoTwitter [url_removed_on_purpose],
  'id': '01a9a39529b27f36',
  'geo': {'type': 'Feature',
   'bbox': [-74.026675, 40.683935, -73.910408, 40.877483],
   'properties': {}},
  'country_code': 'US',
  'name': 'Manhattan',
  'place_type': 'city',
  'country': 'United States',
  'full_name': 'Manhattan, NY'}}
```